# Django Fernet Fields and Data in Transit

Tags: django, database, ssl, encryption

Does django-fernetfields also encrypt the data in transit?

Or does it only encrypt the data at rest?

I am wondering if I also need to encrypt the database connection from the Django app to the database server. I do have https enabled for the site.

Or is django fernet fields already sending and receiving encrypted data across the wire (app<---->db).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://django-fernet-fields.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage), django-fernet-fields encrypts and decrypts the data at the application level, meaning that the data sent to the database during write is already encrypted, and the data read from the database is encrypted.

Of course, this only applies to encrypted ferent fields, with the types mentioned in the [documentation](https://django-fernet-fields.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#field-types).